# Is there a hotkey to open a bookmark in the bookmark bar in Chrome on macOS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

It seems like `⌘ + L` goes to search bar and `⌘ + shift + b` shows/hides the bookmarks bar under the search bar..

but is there a way to e.g. tab through the bookmarks in that bar?

bookmark bar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this indirectly… the same as any menu bar item - because all bookmark bar shortcuts are also in the main menu.

In Ventura it's in System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > App Shortcuts.

Pictures from Mojave, but the operation is the same.

Click the + button, find Google Chrome in the list of apps.
Type the exact name of the URL's menu item.
Add a hotkey.

[image]

Done.

[image]

You don't need to add any menu 'path' unless an item appears in more than one menu. It will just find it.